# Problem to download csv file with ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download in ASP.NET app csv file from service response. Service response contains file content , encoded by base64 . I am trying to download as text file ( without any parsing )- thus set MIME type as text/plain. Filename is .csv Getting error message :

Message: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details: Error parsing

Is there some wrong in values passed for file saving ? Is there means that extension is *.csv and causes to parsing ? Thanks in advance

Here is code for file saving :

````
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", contentBytes.Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType; //passed "text/plain"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(contentBytes);           
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true; 
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```
````

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: [mcve]  @LarsNielsen you can type `[ mcve ]` without the spaces.

Comment: @JeremyThompson thanks I did not know that was an option!

Comment: help, faq and I think tour [faq], [help], [tour]

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(contentBytes);`

I think you need to do a Write not BinaryWrite:

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringBuilderOrStringNotBinary.ToString());`

CSV isn't Binary and I think its best practice to specify the correct MIME Type:

`HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";`

Or use the correct MIME type (and extension) for encoded by base64.